# Plot using dataframe pandas (ylabel)

Tags: python, pandas, plot, dataframe

I have the followed data frame:

```
 frame1 = pd.DataFrame(res.items(), columns=['Region', 'Ratio'])

    Region      Ratio
  0 Midwest     0.005669
  1 Northeast   0.008920
  2 North       0.006374
  3 South       0.002904
  4 Southeast   0.001928
```

I want now to plot (hbar) of my dataframe above with the ylabel with the name of the regions, however, I only get the number (0 to 4) on y label as follows below:

```
  frame1['Ratio'].plot(y=frame1['Region'], x=frame1['Ratio'], kind="barh", align='center', color='blue')
```

[image]

How can I plot the name of each regions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index will be the `yaxis` label, you can try this:

```
ax = frame1.set_index('Region').plot(kind="barh", align='center', color='blue')
```

[image]